# Python PIL.Image opening a .gif and then saving it causes it to have artefacts. How to fix this?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

When I try to open .gif file with Image.open(...) and then save it with Image.save(...) it causes artefacts to appear. What I want to know if there is a way to solve this in Python.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("k.gif")
im.save("k_new.gif", "gif", save_all=True)
```

[3rd frame of the gif before applying that Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWhIC.png)

[3rd frame after applying that python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2U64.png)

P.s. As I understand this is due to gif optimization, but what I want to know if there is way to not get these artefacts after using Python PIL.Image to open the .gif file. I have looked around and about this, but haven't anything that would solve this.